# How to activate scroll on main panel after scroll on sidebar is complete?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am trying to replicate the scrolling behavior like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp).
When you scroll the sidebar, it keeps scrolling until it reaches the end. Then any further scrolling on the sidebar is actually scrolled on the main panel. I have the following code:

```
<div className='wrapper'>
        <div className='sidebar'>My sidebar</div>
        <div className='main-panel'>
          //this is the main panel content on which overflow y scroll is enabled
          <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-md-8' id='col-1'>
              This is the column content I want to scroll when end
              of my scroll content of col-2 is reached
            </div>
            <div className='col-md-4' id='col-2'>
              This is the column which when scrolled to the end
              will then scroll col-1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: If you can make a jsfiddle including bootstrap etc I'll fix it for you rather quickly

Answer (score 0):

The basic browser behavior is very simple. Scroll the element under the cursor, if it's at maximum then bubble the event up the DOM.

So the only thing you should do is put the sidebar in the main content. That way both will scroll.

You that W3C example you gave, the sidebar and the document body scroll. Since the sidebar is included in the body, the behavior you want works.

Comment: Noted, but if I put the sidebar in the main content, how am I supposed to achieve the bootstrap grid system, where the main content spans 8 columns and right next to it the sidebar spans 4 columns.

Comment: My first suggestion would be 'you don't". Create your main content the full 12, put the sidebar and your content there. The problem you have is that you want to scroll the content, while the best way to do it is just make the page scroll, the content will follow...

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using fixed sidebar, so when you scroll down your sidebar, the main content will start to scroll (up or down). There you have simple example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you please reproduce an example that works with the bootstrap layout provided?

Comment: I believe you need to write JS code to detect if scroll position is on the very top/bottom and in that case scroll the other part of application. If you want to achieve this behavior I suggest to reorganize the html/css to make it natively, if this is no possible you need to write the function as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve it in that setup, there is small js code which should help you:

```
const sidebar = document.getElementById('col-1');

const container = document.getElementById('col-2');

sidebar.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  const { target } = event;
  
  const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = sidebar;
  
  if (scrollTop + clientHeight === scrollHeight) {
    //scrolledDown
    container.scrollTop += 20
  }
  
  if(scrollTop === 0) {
    //scrolledUp
    container.scrollTop -= 20
  }
})
```